# Counting the number of distinct s-t cuts in a oriented graph

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, counting-complexity

I am trying to find the number of distinct s-t cuts in a oriented unweighed graph. In an article [Enumeration in Graphs](http://www.cs.uu.nl/research/techreps/repo/CS-1987/1987-07.pdf) p. 45 I found good way how to enumerate those cuts (section 7.3). Is there a faster or simpler algorithm I can use if I am interested only in the number of such cuts and I do not actually need to enumerate it?

The definition of a s-t cut I am using is following. We have a directed graph where two vertices are labelled **S** and **T**. Cut is a *minimal* set of edges of a graph such that by removing those edges there will no longer exist a path from vertex **S** to vertex **T**.

I tried to [ask this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343263) at Stack Overflow and I have been pointed here.

Comment: If your graph is planar, then you can do this in $O(n^2)$ time. See http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2011.05.017.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Counting the number of s,t-cuts is #P-complete.  This is a result by Provan and Ball.

- J. Scott Provan, Michael O. Ball: The Complexity of Counting Cuts and of Computing the Probability that a Graph is Connected. SIAM J. Comput. 12(4): 777-788 (1983)

Therefore, unless some complexity-theoretic collapse happens, you cannot get essentially faster algorithm than listing all of them.

Comment: Is the complexity of counting _minimum_ s,t-cuts also hard?

Comment: Yes, that is also hard.

Comment: That's interesting, as there are only $n^{2\alpha}$ (not s-t) cuts that are within $\alpha$ of the minimum. Is the exact number of minimum cuts easy to compute?

Comment: @Sasho Nikolov: The number of min-cuts in an $n$-vertex undirected graph is at most $\binom{n}{2}$, and they can be listed in polynomial time.  So, the number of min-cuts can be computed in polynomial time.

Comment: is the same true for $\alpha$-approximate min cuts?

Comment: There is no need to complexity collapse to solve problem in better than listing all of them for example may be there is some sub exponential algorithm for counting this, it doesn't cause to P=NP.

Comment: @Saeed: Right, and that's why I put "essentially" in the sentence.

Comment: @SashoNikolov: For the approximation, I don't know.  But, I guess it's also possible as long as $\alpha$ is constant.

Comment: @YoshioOkamoto, I thought about your "essentially" (at first) I guess you mean some polynomial time difference, but IMHO $2^n \gt\gt 2^{sqrt(n)}$ or something similar, this can be a good results and solvable in many cases. (if exists)

Comment: @Saeed: I agree.

Comment: @YoshiOkamoto, How many s-t minimal cuts will be there in a graph of size $n$. Is it exponential or polynomial ?

Comment: @Kumar: It is an exercise to show the number of minimum s-t cuts can be exponential.